# Is it possible to multiply the string 10 with number 10

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

Multiplying `'10' * 10` is giving some output value `10101010101010101010`

Could any one justify it?

```
ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
System.out.println(parser.parseExpression("'10' * 10").getValue());
```

Output : `10101010101010101010`

Comment: What output did you expect?

Comment: What did you expect from expression "string '10' ten times?"

Comment: try Integer.parseInt()

Comment: @Eran == >  It should throw some exception as in java we cannot multiply string with number.

Comment: @PavelSmirnov ==> : ) Yes got it!!

Comment: @UdayKumar I don't know if you know much about Java, but '10' is not a String.

Comment: @Stultuske : HeHe !! here context is not that Even System.out.println(parser.parseExpression("\"10\" * 10").getValue());  is giving same output!!

Comment: @Stultuske : What does that mean then?

Comment: What does what mean?

Comment: Spring Expression Language (SpEL) != Java

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Ok.

Comment: @Stultuske Could you please tell how spel is considering '10' ?

Comment: You have this marked as a Java question. I was talking about Java

Comment: @Stultuske To reach java people I have marked it like that!! I am Sure the code written there  is java

Comment: @UdayKumar in Java, '10' would never compile. You are looking for a specific framework, yet are asking about basic Java components.

Comment: @Stultuske Could you please let me know where I have asked about basic java components?

Comment: @UdayKumar you assume a String is not a basic java component?

Comment: If you assume String means only  java I can't help you in this case!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It should throw some exception as in java we cannot multiply string with number.

SpEL **is not Java** it has some similarities, but it's **not Java**. It doesn't have lambdas, it has different syntax for many things.

The multiplier operator applied to a string means concatenate the string that number of times.

Similar to `'10' + '10' = '1010'`,  `'10' * 2 = '1010'`.

Javadoc in the `OpMultiply` class:

```
/**
 * Implements the {@code multiply} operator directly here for certain types
 * of supported operands and otherwise delegates to any registered overloader
 * for types not supported here.
 * <p>Supported operand types:
 * <ul>
 * <li>numbers
 * <li>String and int ('abc' * 2 == 'abcabc')
 * </ul>
 */
```